# Using functools.reduce to find max-min of everything to the left of List every time an element+1< element

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, functools

In dict1 there is a list of samples for one day as a list and date object as key. Im then using that dict1 to find the total usage for the day based on certain scenarios.

1. First check that every `sample +1 > sample`  if not then a rollover happened and do the following.

   - check that there exist a previous day to compare and the max
     value of the day is greater than the previous day max. If thats
     all true then take the difference between the current max value
     and previous day max value to get partial usage. Then continue.
   - Once the above is checked then start by finding
     everywhere sample+1 > sample and take the min - max of the set of
     samples to left.
   - Then add all those values from the resulting sets to get one
     value the daily usage.

The reduce function seems to work great for finding rollovers but I cant seem to find when `element +1 < element` using the lambda function? The resulting dictionary should read for date1 and date2 `{date1_object:9610068.0 - 9609363.0 ,date2_Object :(9610503.0 - 9610068.0) + (3000-200) + (55-5)}`

```
dict1 = {date1_object:[9609363.0, 9609363.0, 9609504.0, 9609645.0, 9609787.0,
     9609925.0, 9610068.0],
        date2_object: [9610358.0, 9610503.0, 200.0, 3000.0, 5.0, 50.0, 55.0]}
    total = None
    dict2 = {}
    for i in dict1:
        for j in range(len(dict1.get(i))-1):
            if dict1[i][j+1] < dict1[i][j]:
                if max(dict1.get(k)) > max(dict1.get(k-time_delta)):
                   temp_list.append(max(dict1.get(k)) - max(dict1.get(k-time_delta)))
                else: 
                   temp_list.append(reduce(lambda x, y: y-x , dict1.get(i)))
            total = sum(temp_list)
            dict2[i] = total
            elif:
                # some other logic I'll do
```

*Note the example I show for date1 and date2 is just a high level example of what should be happening.

Comment: `dict1` is not a valid data structure and yields SyntaxErrors

Comment: @C.Nivs I fixed that issue lets just call them date objects for simplicity.

Comment: time_delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1) just help with checking for previous days.

Comment: I think it would help if you made it more clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to make a new dictionary showing the change between two days in the first dictionary?

Comment: @AlexS I updated the post for more clarity. But basically Im trying to take dict1 and get the total daily usage. I for one check that the daily samples are always incrementing. If not a rollover happened and I need to break the list up to find everywhere that sample + 1 < sample and find the max - min for the set of values to the left.

Comment: For the day the rollover happened though I can get some partial usage based on the previous day by finding the last max value and comparing it to the previous day max if I have previous day to compare, the I can continue with the rest of list as mentioned above. Does that now make sense? @AlexS